# OraOLEDB.Oracle connection string

Tags: oracle, vbscript

I am trying to connect to oracle using a vbscript.  I can connect using the tns name using sql*plus, tnsping, etc.

Here's the vbscript

```
Dim connect

Set connect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

connect.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" & _
    "Data Source=tnsname;" & _
    "User Id=usrid;" & _
    "Password=pw;"

connect.Open
```

I get error

> ora_dl.vbs(9, 1) OraOLEDB: ORA-12154: TNS:could not re solve the connect identifier specified

Answer (score 0):

The connection string to use diverses from server to server, depending on the version of Oracle and its OleDB drivers, I have to check mine everytime this changes.

See [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/) site for the possible connections strings and try some others.